# Setting buildOptimizer to true in angular.json causes application to not work correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have an Angular 11.1 application and if I build it with the setting buildOptimizer set to true in angular.json, it builds with no errors and loads with no errors but it doesn't work correctly.  Some pages will hang and others won't have the screens rendered correctly.  Some pages work fine and there are no errors.  If I build it with this setting set to false everything works correctly.

I'm looking for some way to find out what is wrong because it builds and runs without any errors.  Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

My angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myproject": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "msgpack5",
              "@progress/kendo-angular-intl/locales/en-GB/all",
              "@progress/kendo-angular-intl/locales/en/all",
              "@progress/kendo-angular-intl/locales/en-AU/all",
              "file-saver",
              "xlsx",
              "hammerjs"
            ],
            "aot": true,
            "progress": false,
            "verbose": false,
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.browser.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills/browser.polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/favicon.svg"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/material.theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/mdc-light-deeppurple/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css",
              "node_modules/tippy.js/dist/backdrop.css",
              "node_modules/tippy.js/dist/svg-arrow.css",
              "node_modules/tippy.js/dist/tippy.css",
              "node_modules/tippy.js/themes/material.css",
              "src/cb-theme.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": {
                "scripts": false,
                "styles": false,
                "vendor": false
              },
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "cb:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "cb:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "cb:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills/browser.polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/cb-theme.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/favicon.svg"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options":
          {
            "lintFilePatterns":
            [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist-server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": true,
                "vendor": true
              },
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": {
                "scripts": false,
                "styles": false,
                "vendor": false
              },
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "cb-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "cb:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "cb",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```